# Argument placeholder

Tags: jquery

The following piece of code from the jQuery source caught my eye (line 7716 from the latest revision bit.ly/jqsource):

```
        send: function( _, callback ) {

            script = document.createElement( "script" );

            script.async = "async";

// BLA BLA BLA
        }
```

At no point is the named parameter `_` used. It seems this is to force `callback` to be `arguments[1]` instead of `arguments[0]`. Why would that be useful?

Comment: The only reason I can think that would be useful is if the function is meant to be curried and the first argument is meaningless in this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's merely a convention adopted to reference non-used parameters.

If they didn't have *some* parameter name there, the only way to get the second argument would be to do:

```
arguments[1];
```

...and that would bring us back to your earlier question about JSLint complaining about static reference to individual members of the `arguments` object.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source, depending on the result of `jQuery.support.ajax`, `jQuery.ajaxTransport` gets assigned one of two functions.

The first one you saw has this signature:

```
send: function( _, callback )
```

Which means the first argument is not used.

The second one on the other hand (search for `send:` on the source), has this signature:

```
send: function( headers, complete )
```

In order to maintain a common interface for the send method, the first one has to accept the parameters even if they are not used.

BTW, the first one doesn't seem to use the `headers` since it simulates a request using a `<script/>` element.